# Possible to change Delphi search history list

Tags: delphi, ide

In the Delphi 10.3 IDE, using the Find function, when I press the down arrow in the search item edit I get an alphabetical list of everything I've ever searched for. But using the Find In Files function, when I press the down arrow in the search item edit I get a list of my most recent search items. Is there a way to control which list is presented? I'd much prefer the most recently used list in both search functions.

Thanks

Comment: Interestingly, this seems not to be the case in my RAD Studio 10.3. I get the items sorted by time.

Comment: Do you have _MMX Code Explorer_ installed? There is a setting in _General - Delphi-Editor_ named _Enable IDE Search Enhancement_, which might have to be disabled.

Comment: @UweRaabe I do have MMX. Thank you!